How to make all possible combinations of several strings
I have a previously unknown number of words, stored for convenience within a TStringList object.
var
  input_list: TStringList;
begin
  input_list := TStringList.Create;
  input_list.Add('Mark');
  input_list.Add('Anna');
  input_list.Add('John');
  input_list.Add('Martha');
  ...
end;

I want to make new list containing all possible combinations of these words, from 1 word to N words. The separator is irrelevant:
N = 3
'Mark'
'Anna
'Mark Anna'
'Anna Mark'
'Mark John'
'John Mark'
'Mark Anna John'
'John Anna Mark'
'Anna John Mark'
...

Please note that the above example contains combinations of 1 to N words from the above-mentioned list of words. Moreover, I consider the same words but in a different order to be different, so both 'mark anna' and 'anna mark' should be on the list.
Edit: Please also note that these combinations are without repetitions, i.e. 'mark anna' should be included in the list, but 'mark mark' should not be.
Is there a simple way, like procedure_permutate(list_of_strings)?

There are many algorithms that allows getting desired results. I suggest you learn more about permutations and combinatorics algorithms. Oh and assign each word its onw unique Index since permutations and combinatorics algorithms operate with numbers.

You can use a recursive function, per example;
procedure TForm1.generarCombinaciones(const elementos: TStringList;
  const combinacion: string; inicio: Integer);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  if combinacion <> '' then
    ShowMessage(combinacion);

  for i := inicio to elementos.Count-1 do
    GenerarCombinaciones(elementos, combinacion + elementos.Strings[i] + ' ', i + 1);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
   sl : TStringList;
begin
   sl := TStringList.Create;
   sl.Add('Mark');
   sl.Add('Anna');
   sl.Add('John');
   sl.Add('Martha');

   generarCombinaciones(sl,'',0);

   sl.free;
end;

If you want a maximum depth of 3 elements, you can add a new parameter to the function to check the maximum depth

does this code meet your requirements? Also some recursive approach.
program Project_delphi_stackoverflow;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, Types, Classes;

procedure GeneratePermutations(input_list: TStringList; output_list: TStringList; current_combination: TStringList; used: TBits);
var
  i: Integer;
  combination: string;
begin
  if current_combination.Count > 0 then
  begin
    combination := Trim(current_combination.DelimitedText);
    output_list.Add(combination);
  end;

  for i := 0 to input_list.Count - 1 do
  begin
    if not used[i] then
    begin
      used[i] := True;
      current_combination.Add(input_list[i]);
      GeneratePermutations(input_list, output_list, current_combination, used);
      current_combination.Delete(current_combination.Count - 1);
      used[i] := False;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure OutputCombinations(output_list: TStringList);
var
  combination: string;
begin
  WriteLn('----------------------------------------------------------');
  WriteLn(Format('Number of combinations: %d', [output_list.Count]));
  WriteLn('----------------------------------------------------------');
  for combination in output_list do
    WriteLn(combination);
  WriteLn;
end;

var
  input_list, output_list, current_combination: TStringList;
  used: TBits;

begin
  input_list := TStringList.Create;
  output_list := TStringList.Create;
  current_combination := TStringList.Create;
  used := TBits.Create;
  try
    // Your test data N=4
    input_list.Add('Mark');
    input_list.Add('Anna');
    input_list.Add('John');
    input_list.Add('Martha');
    used.Size := input_list.Count;

    GeneratePermutations(input_list, output_list, current_combination, used);
    OutputCombinations(output_list);

    // Your test data N=5
    input_list.Add('Joe');
    output_list.Clear;
    used.Size := input_list.Count;

    GeneratePermutations(input_list, output_list, current_combination, used);
    OutputCombinations(output_list);

    // Your test data N=6
    input_list.Add('Alice');
    output_list.Clear;
    used.Size := input_list.Count;

    GeneratePermutations(input_list, output_list, current_combination, used);
    OutputCombinations(output_list);


    // Your test data N=4
     input_list.Clear;
    input_list.Add('Mark');
    input_list.Add('Anna');
    input_list.Add('Mark');
    input_list.Add('Martha');
    used.Size := input_list.Count;

    GeneratePermutations(input_list, output_list, current_combination, used);
    OutputCombinations(output_list);

  finally
    input_list.Free;
    output_list.Free;
    current_combination.Free;
    used.Free;
  end;

  ReadLn;
end.

